# Линия под углом 30 градусов

Tags: html

Как в HTML нарисовать линию под углом 30 градусов...

Comment: без использования CSS

Comment: Вставить картинку с такой линией...

Answer (score 4):

[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/HmMHx/1/)

HTML

```
<hr />
```

CSS

```
hr {   
    -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);      
    -moz-transform: rotate(150deg);       
    -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);        
    -o-transform: rotate(150deg);
}
```

или, если наклон в другую сторону

```
hr {   
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);      
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);       
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);        
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

Comment: А без использования CSS???

Comment: Тогда с [помощью PHP](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/gd/Pixel-Line.php)

Answer (score 2):

С использованием JavaScript ([Canvas](http://htmlbook.ru/html5/canvas)):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Так как аргументом функции может быть только радиан,
// а не угол в градусах, то  переводим.
var a = 30 * (Math.PI / 180);

// Длина линии.
var r = 100;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(Math.sin(a) * r, Math.cos(a) * r);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="tutorial" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/a3FFH/)